# Find all unpaired bluetooth devices nearby method is too slow

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have these two lines in my project:

```
 //Gets all unpaired Bluetooth devices
    var unpairedDevices = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false);

    var unpairedNearDevices = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(unpairedDevices)).
        Select(x => x.Name).ToList(); //This line is painfully slow! It takes seconds
```

It works beautifully but it's painfully slow to find all unpaired nearby bluetooth devices even if it only returns like 5 devices. It takes like 10 seconds or something.

Although it's a call within the windows UWP api itself, I'm wondering how or what I can do to improve performance of this call?

Comment: Which of the two lines is slow?

Comment: @mjwills The second line sorry about that.

Comment: How far is the unpaired equipment from your device? I tested different distance, and it would take different time to get the unpaired equipment list.

Comment: Well, I want a list of all unpaired devices. One unpaired device is right next to me, another device is a few cubicles down from me. I'm not sure the exact distance.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT is there a way to return the bluetooth device list that is immediately generated from within the device itself. E.g. if I go to "Settings > bluetooth", I can usually see the list of nearby devices very quickly versus the delay in my app. I was wondering why the performance difference. Is there a way to grab the list that is already generated? Thanks!